# Laravel sort hasMany Country->City Relation

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, has-many, laravel-5

i have the following Models:

Country, CountryTranslation, City, CityTranslation

i want to achieve to get the list of all cities in some country, but they must be sort by their name. The problem is that these city names are in CityTranslation.

Here are the Model definitions:
Country:

```
class Country extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'code', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'currency_id', 'timezone', 'dam_date', 'status',
    ];

public function translations() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CountryTranslation');

}

public function city() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City');

}
```

}

City:

```
class City extends Model {

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'code', 'country_id', 'status',
];

public function translations() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CityTranslation');

}


public function country() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Country');

}
```

}

CityTranslation:

```
class CityTranslation extends Model {

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'lang', 'city_id',
];

public function city() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\City', 'id', 'city_id');
}
```

}

For the moment i get these cities as follows, but they are not ordered:

```
$country = $this->country->findOrFail($id);
foreach (City::where('country_id', '=', $id)->get() as $cur) {
    $city_trans = CityTranslation::where(array(['city_id', '=', $cur->id], ['lang', '=', Lang::getLocale()]))->orderBy('name', 'asc')->first();
    $cities_by_country[$cur->id] = $city_trans->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Country` model you may use something like this:

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City')->orderBy('name');
}
```

Then, when you are querying a `Country` use `with` for example:

```
$countryWithCity = Country::with('city')->findOrFail($id);
```

So, the `$countryWithCity->city` will be ordered.

Comment: I will try that later, but i dont think that will work for me, cause the field 'name' is in the CityTranslation model, so that need to be sorted ?